# How far does a Scanner can read (in Java)? Can I modify it bigger?

Tags: java

I need to input an array of String (very large Strings, about 3000 characters per String). But when I read my input by Scanner, it didn't read all of them. For example, with 100 lines input, it only read to 63rd lines
This is what I got when run it on ideone: http://ideone.com/57uugH
Here is my code:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String s;
        int t;
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        try {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sc.reset();
                s = sc.nextLine();
                al.add(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Numbers of Index in Arraylist: " + al.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you need to read from the input, and do you need to use Scanner?  It would be better to store data in a file and read that in.

Comment: How are you inputting those lines? Typing? Pasting?

Comment: Scanner reads until the end, there's no "size" that would limit the amount you can read. Your `sc.reset();` is completely unnecessary and the issue is not with `Scanner` having some internal limits.

Comment: this is a problem on SPOJ, I'm trying to complete it, it's not from file, just input on console screen

Comment: the first line shows the total of testcase (100 lines below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input has `62` lines and `186` words (`61` and `185` excluding first line). If you want to read all words you can use this:

```
String s;
int t;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
t = sc.nextInt();
try {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
            s = sc.next();
            al.add(s);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this case your `t` is not used. If you want to read not more than `t` (`100`) words then try this:

```
String s;
int t;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
t = sc.nextInt();
try {
    while (sc.hasNext() && t-->0) {
            s = sc.next();
            al.add(s);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: okay I see now, the reason is my input has only 63 lines, I copied & pasted but the "stdin" on ideone doesn't save all of them. Thanks so much